# Highcharts milliseconds displaying incorrectly in xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having trouble having highcharts correctly format (or even format at all) the milliseconds I have listed as the categories of my xaxis.  My xAxis object looks as follows:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [1373155200000, 1373241600000, 1373328000000, 1373414400000, 1373500800000, 1373587200000, 1373673600000, 1373760000000, 1373846400000, 1373932800000, 1374019200000, 1374105600000],
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {

            millisecond: '%H',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%e. %b',
            month: '%b \'%y',
            year: '%Y'

        }
    }
```

But the xaxis of my graph is still displaying the labels as milliseconds.  The tooltip parses the label correctly.

Here's a jsfiddle I have displaying the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/WSsZz/2/

Any pointers will help!

Comment: Is this what you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/WSsZz/3/

Comment: It pointed me in the right direction.  It's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine a datetime axis with categories - it is strictly one or the other.

Using the formatter to calculate the labels from the categories is a pretty bizarre way to go about this...

you simply need to remove the categories and send your date/time values as your x data values, or, use the pointStart and pointInterval properties if your data points are at equal intervals.